# Laravel Nova Metrics - how to show number without k

Tags: laravel-nova

I generate metrics with Laravel Nova to show sales.
The problem is that it shows me numbers like 0.50k instead of 500

Answer (score 4):

To show thousands "normally" you can use the format method like this:

```
public function calculate(Request $request)
{
    return $this->count($request, Sales::class)->format('0,0');
}
```